# Spring JPA : Multiple Aurora RDS MySQL operation is taking too much time

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, amazon-aurora

Having POST API which insert data into multiple tables. (MySQL)

Implementation is using JPA.

Below are sequence of operation which are happening, any suggestion : how to optimize this.

**SQL Queries :**

```
1) Select * from University where UID = 'UNI1';
2) If (University Not Exist) then Insert INTO University ...

3) Select * from College where UID = 'UNI1'
4) If (College Not Exist) then Insert INTO College ...

**In Loop (For Each Student)**

5) Delete * from CollegeStudent;

LOOP :

6) Select * from Student where StudentId = 'ST22'
7) If (Student Not Exist) then Insert INTO Student ...

8)  Insert INTO CollegeStudent (Student, College);

LOOP ENDS;
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
      @Transactional      

      public void persistStudentResults(String universityId, String collegeId, List<Student> studentList) {
            University university= universityRepository.findByUniversityId(universityId);
            if (university == null) {
                university = createUniversityObject(universityId);
                universityRepository.save(university );
            }

            College college = collegeRepository.getCollegeByCollegeId(university.getUniversityId(), collegeId);

            if (college == null) {
                college = createCollegeObject(university , collegeId);
                collegeRepository.save(deviceDetails);
            }


            collegeStudentRepository.deleteByCollegeId(university.getUniversityId(), college.getCollegeId());

            for (Student student: studentList) {
                Student dbStudent = studentRepository.findByStudentId(student.getStudentId());

                if (dbStudent == null) {
                    dbStudent = createStudentObject(student);
                    studentRepository.save(dbStudent);                    
                }

                CollegeStudent collegeStudent = createCollegeStudentObject(dbStudent, college);
                collegeStudentRepository.save(collegeStudent);
            }
        }
```

**Hibernate Logs :**

```
className=org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener, methodName=end> StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
   308714170 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
   0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
   524069 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
   309001256 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
   0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
   0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
   0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
   0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
   197852 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 0 collections);
   0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

It seems for each save() it is creating new connection.

---

### **Time Taken :**

Number of Students : 5

MySQL DB :  243 ms

Aurora DB  :    **32 sec**

(If directly inserted into DB using DBeaver : 1.5 Sec)

---

Number of Students : 30

MySQL DB :  1 sec

Aurora DB  :    **173 sec**

(If directly inserted into DB using DBeaver : 9 Sec)

---

Comment: So without the actually code you expect us to guess your actual implementation and give you a solution?

Comment: Updated code snippet

Comment: And what exactly takes too much time now? What times have you measured?

Comment: Updated in question

Answer (score 0):

Add index keys to mostly use columns in  your tables.

Comment: Same query works fine on MySQL, but on Aurora it's too slow

Comment: increase your connection pool

Comment: till issue persist. It taking too long in acquiring connection , create query and execution

Comment: Do you have any suggestion it happen